# Deployed FastAPI application on dashboard.render.com results in 404 Not Found

Tags: fastapi, render.com

I'm attempting to deploy [a FastAPI application](https://github.com/JayZeeDesign/researcher-gpt/blob/main/app.py) on dashboard.render.com.

```py
# (Abridged code for brevity...)
app = FastAPI()

class Query(BaseModel):
    query: str

@app.post("/")
def researchAgent(query: Query):
    query = query.query
    content = agent({"input": query})
    actual_content = content['output']
    return actual_content
```

When deploying this on render.com, the service starts correctly but when accessing it, I get a `404 Not Found` error. The logs I receive are:

```
Aug 9 07:10:28 PM  INFO:     34.83.63.75:0 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

However, it seems the service is running correctly:

```
Aug 9 07:10:24 PM  INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:10000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Any idea what might be causing this and how I can resolve the `404 Not Found` error?

Comment: You're sending a GET request, but you only have a POST endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that you are exposing the wrong port. Are you sure you've configured the port to be `10000` on Render?

I was able to deploy FastAPI application following this guide to a platform similar to Render: https://docs.porter.run/language-specific-guides/fastapi

Not sure what your `Dockerfile` looks like, but the `Dockerfile` in this guide should work just as well on Render.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if the GitHub link you posted is all of your code or not, but it looks like you're not setting your CORSMiddleware for the FastAPI application. You're going to need to set the origins, headers, etc.

Check [this link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/?h=cors) out.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "https://localhost.tiangolo.com",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

If that doesn't work, try making a health-check API endpoint and hitting it with Postman.

Do one for GET and POST.